# Use a text input as a password html JavaScript but not type=password

Tags: html, text, input, passwords

I have a predicament where I need a standard text input box to act like a password input without the type=password attribute.

The reason being is the app for a specific reason does not want password managers to be triggered by it.

Basically I was thinking

```
<script>
var mypw ="";
</script>

<input type="text" onkeydown="updatethis(this)"     onpaste="updatethis(this)">
```

After this I am lost, but somehow i want the pw to be stored in mypw and the input to just show a security char.

Again the need is very unique but I need to avoid password managers from triggering in this one scenario.

Comment: I need it to work in all browsers.  Edge and ie don't support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the color and background to white, then mapped a divider right on top of it and updated in jquery.

```
                        <input class="noselect" type="text" id="password"
                            placeholder="Click2Mail Password" name="password" value="" onkeyUp="updatePW();"
                            required><div id="pwchar" onclick="$('#password').focus();" style="font-weight: 300;font-size:14px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;margin-top:12px;margin-left:38px;z-index:999999999999999999;"></div>
```

Here is the jquery

```
function updatePW()
{

    $("#pwchar").html($('#password').val().replace(/./g,"*"));
}
```

and last the css to make sure you cannot select the text in the box

```
#password{ -webkit-text-security: disc;background-color:#fff;color:#fff;
 }
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */

}
```

It's def not the perfect solution, but it works.

Answer (score 4):

You mean something like?

```css
input{
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
```

Comment: I need it to work in all browsers.  Edge and ie do not support it.